Yesterday, I set up SSH. Today, Emacs crashes on boot. How to fix?
Yesterday, I didn't change anything in Emacs. All that I did was set up SSH through ssh-add and ssh-keygen. Today, Emacs crashes moments after opening. I suspect the two are related. How can I debug this?
On some OS boots, the bug is not present at all. One day, it only crashed once. On other boots, it crashes every time.
Running /usr/bin/emacs/ in the terminal before a crash reports

Fatal error 11: Segmentation fault
Aborted (core dumped)

I open Emacs with either
/usr/bin/emacs %F

or
sh -c "if [ -n \\"\\$*\\" ]; then exec /usr/bin/emacsclient --alternate-editor= --reuse-frame \\"\\$@\\"; else exec emacsclient --alternate-editor= --create-frame; fi" sh %F

or
/usr/bin/emacsclient --alternate-editor= --create-frame %F

Emacs has never crashed while using /usr/bin/emacs -Q, but I don't have any idea what in my .emacs file could be causing this problem. I am slowly searching through it.
Important note: When re-opening Emacs after a crash, I am asked if I want to use my Desktop file. Refusing seems to prevent the crashes.
.xsession-errors:

dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DISPLAY=:0
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XAUTHORITY=/home/MyAccount/.Xauthority
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=XFCE
/etc/X11/Xsession.d/30x11-common_xresources: line 16: has_option: command not found
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/xfce4:/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop
/etc/X11/Xsession.d/75dbus_dbus-launch: line 9: has_option: command not found
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1
/etc/X11/Xsession.d/90x11-common_ssh-agent: line 9: has_option: command not found
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SHELL=/bin/bash
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg/xdg-xubuntu:/etc/xdg
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting CLUTTER_BACKEND=x11
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LANGUAGE=en_GB:en
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting MANDATORY_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/xubuntu.mandatory.path
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DESKTOP_SESSION=xubuntu
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting PWD=/home
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP=xubuntu
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LOGNAME=MyAccount
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=gtk2
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_SESSION_TYPE=x11
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GPG_AGENT_INFO=/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XAUTHORITY=/home/MyAccount/.Xauthority
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_GREETER_DATA_DIR=/var/lib/lightdm-data
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GDM_LANG=en_GB
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting HOME=/home
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting IM_CONFIG_PHASE=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=XFCE
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DOTNET_BUNDLE_EXTRACT_BASE_DIR=/home/MyAccount/.cache/dotnet_bundle_extract
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting CLUTTER_IM_MODULE=ibus
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_SESSION_CLASS=user
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GTK_OVERLAY_SCROLLING=0
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DEFAULTS_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/xubuntu.default.path
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting USER=MyAccount
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DISPLAY=:0
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SHLVL=0
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT_IM_MODULE=ibus
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DEBUGINFOD_URLS=https://debuginfod.ubuntu.com
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/xubuntu:/usr/share/xfce4:/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting PATH=/home/MyAccount/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/MyAccount/.dotnet/tools
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GDMSESSION=xubuntu
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting _=/usr/bin/dbus-update-activation-environment
/usr/bin/iceauth:  creating new authority file /run/user/1000/ICEauthority
xfce4-session-Message: 06:22:02.983: GNOME compatibility is enabled and gnome-keyring-daemon is found on the system. Skipping gpg/ssh-agent startup.
discover_other_daemon: 1
(xfsettingsd:2572): xfconf-WARNING **: 06:22:03.547: Failed to set property "displays::/ActiveProfile": Operation was cancelled
Failure: No such entity
(polkit-mate-authentication-agent-1:2636): GLib-CRITICAL **: 06:22:04.200: g_variant_new_string: assertion 'string != NULL' failed
(polkit-mate-authentication-agent-1:2636): polkit-mate-1-WARNING **: 06:22:04.202: Failed to register client: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
Cannot register authentication agent: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: An authentication agent already exists for the given subject
error: autostart failed:

"ubuntu-software-service.desktop": skipped

[Parent 2862, IPC I/O Parent] WARNING: process 3080 is a zombie: file /builds/worker/checkouts/gecko/ipc/chromium/src/base/process_util_posix.cc:245
[Parent 2862, IPC I/O Parent] WARNING: process 3085 is a zombie: file /builds/worker/checkouts/gecko/ipc/chromium/src/base/process_util_posix.cc:245
[Parent 3436, IPC I/O Parent] WARNING: process 3643 is a zombie: file /builds/worker/checkouts/gecko/ipc/chromium/src/base/process_util_posix.cc:245
[Parent 3436, IPC I/O Parent] WARNING: process 3512 is a zombie: file /builds/worker/checkouts/gecko/ipc/chromium/src/base/process_util_posix.cc:245
[Parent 3436, IPC I/O Parent] WARNING: process 3714 is a zombie: file /builds/worker/checkouts/gecko/ipc/chromium/src/base/process_util_posix.cc:245
[Parent 2862, IPC I/O Parent] WARNING: process 3263 is a zombie: file /builds/worker/checkouts/gecko/ipc/chromium/src/base/process_util_posix.cc:245
[Parent 2862, IPC I/O Parent] WARNING: process 3860 is a zombie: file /builds/worker/checkouts/gecko/ipc/chromium/src/base/process_util_posix.cc:245
[Parent 2862, IPC I/O Parent] WARNING: process 3958 is a zombie: file /builds/worker/checkouts/gecko/ipc/chromium/src/base/process_util_posix.cc:245
[Parent 2862, IPC I/O Parent] WARNING: process 4154 is a zombie: file /builds/worker/checkouts/gecko/ipc/chromium/src/base/process_util_posix.cc:245
[Parent 2862, IPC I/O Parent] WARNING: process 4155 is a zombie: file /builds/worker/checkouts/gecko/ipc/chromium/src/base/process_util_posix.cc:245
[Parent 2862, IPC I/O Parent] WARNING: process 4069 is a zombie: file /builds/worker/checkouts/gecko/ipc/chromium/src/base/process_util_posix.cc:245


Does /usr/bin/emacs -Q fail, as well?

@choroba That seems to work. How much does that narrow things down?

It means the problem lies in your init file (~/.emacs, ~/.emacs.d/init.el, or ~/.config/emacs/init.el).

@choroba Interesting. I have nothing ssh related there. My only guess is (exec-path-from-shell-initialize). I'll binary search through the list to see what's really causing it, but is that a likely candidate?

Open a terminal and start Emacs from the command line in that terminal (/usr/bin/emacs): what does it say when it crashes?

@NickD "Fatal error 11: Segmentation fault
Aborted (core dumped)"

@choroba I've updated the question. Thanks.

Was the core file saved somewhere? If so, you can use gdb to examine it and get a backtrace. I don't know how informative it would be, but it's not as if you have much choice at this point. But you might want to go down the path you are on as far as you can first: you can bisect your init file if you want to speed up that process.

@NickD Does it have a typical save location?

I believe it depends on your system. Do man core from the command line for more info. On my Fedora 40 Linux system, they are stored in /var/lib/systemd/coredump.

@NickD No results. /var/crash/ has a 50 MB _usr_bin_emacs-gtk.1000.crash file, but gdb emacs '/var/crash/_usr_bin_emacs-gtk.1000.crash' insists that the file isn't a coredump.

What OS are you using? What does file /var/crash/_usr_bin_emacs-gtk.1000.crash say? It may be that the file is compressed. On Fedora, it is compressed to a .zst file, but YMMV.

@NickD Xubuntu. Your code reports /var/crash/_usr_bin_emacs-gtk.1000.crash: ASCII text.

So it's a big text file: you can use less on it if you want or open it in Emacs (but it is big). See this answer on AskUbuntu for a method to extract the core dump and use gdb on it. Also search for crash on AskUbuntu for other possibilities (apport-retrace gets mentioned frequently). But that's as far as I can go (I'm not an Ubuntu user). Good luck!
